# Post indivudal results to FlowLayoutPanel without waiting

Tags: c#

I am adding items into a FlowLayoutPanel. Each item does a ping test to an IP address and posts whether its up or down. The issue I have: nothing gets posted to the FlowLayoutPanel until every item has a result. I want each item to post as its completed and not wait for all of them to complete. I was thinking there may be a way to use threading to do this? I'm not really sure at this point. Some guidance would be great! Here is what the foreach loop looks like:

```
            string[] ipList = ipListTextBox.Text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            statusFlowPanel.Controls.Clear();
            statusFlowPanel.Controls.Add(p1);
            foreach (string ip in ipList)
            {;
                Label ipAddressLabel = new Label();
                ipAddressLabel.Text = ip;

                Label statusLabel = new Label();
                statusLabel.Text = "Status: ";
                statusLabel.Location = new Point(20, 10 + x);

                PictureBox updownPicBox = new PictureBox();
                updownPicBox.Height = 30;
                updownPicBox.Width = 30;
                updownPicBox.Location = new Point(80, 0);

                Ping pingSender = new Ping();
                IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
                PingReply reply = pingSender.Send(address);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    updownPicBox.Image = Properties.Resources.up_arrow;
                }
                else
                {
                    updownPicBox.Image = Properties.Resources.down_arrow;
                }

                var ipPanel = new Panel();
                //Invoke(new Action(() => ));
                statusFlowPanel.Controls.Add(ipPanel);
                ipPanel.Controls.Add(updownPicBox);
                ipPanel.Controls.Add(statusLabel);
                ipPanel.Controls.Add(ipAddressLabel);
                ipPanel.Height = 40;
                x++;
            }
```

Comment: Which version of .net are you targeting?

Comment: Reason I'm asking is because some really useful namespaces aren't available prior to .net 4.0, namely System.Threading.Task...and there's async/await in .net 4.5. In .net 2.0 you could use a BackgroundWorker... answers to this question can vary tremendously depending on the framework version you're targeting.

Comment: I am using .net 4. I can upgrade to 4.5. I have no limitations on which version i use.

Comment: I'm guessing your bottleneck is `pingSender.Send()`.. sorry for not getting back earlier, I thought there would already be answers by now! I think I'd move the body of the loop into its own method, returning a `Panel` with its contents ready to be added to the `statusFlowPanel`... but that's only step 1, I'll post an answer when I have a bit more time :)

Comment: Wow still no answer?! I finally found time to put my thoughts in code, see below :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways to go about this.

This should give you an idea of the direction to take, should work under .net 4.0+ - note that the main/UI thread is waiting for the loop to finish, so you don't have a responsive UI while this is happening, but this code creates a `List<Task>` so you can run them whichever way you prefer:

```
private Panel GetStatusPanel(string ip)
{
    var result = new Panel();
    result.Controls.Add(new Label { Text = ip });
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // do the ping here, populate result panel accordingly
    return result;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ipList = new List<string> { "127.0.0.1", "192.168.0.1", "whatever" };

    statusFlowPanel.Controls.Clear();
    var tasks = ipList.Select(ip => new Task(() => 
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                statusFlowPanel.Controls.Add(GetStatusPanel(ip));
                statusFlowPanel.Refresh();
            }))
        ).ToList();

    tasks.ForEach(t => t.Start());
}
```

This will add the status panels to your `statusFlowPanel` as the ping results come in.